# How do I scp from a server with a variable as the file path?

Tags: bash, scp

I am trying to write a bash script that (1) finds the newest file matching a string pattern on a server and (2) copies that file from the server to my local. I have completed the first part but am having trouble with the second.

I have tried all combinations of using quotes, curly braces, escaping the colon, hard coding the root folder on the server, but none of it works.

`file_name=$(ssh -t id@server.com "ls -t /path/to/file/on/server/file_name_* | head -1; bash -l")
echo $file_name #this works
scp id@server.com:$file_name path/to/local #this does not work`

Line 2 works, so I assume line 1 works. I can run line 3 with no problems when I type the command into terminal with `file_name` hard coded. When I run this script, I get an error saying `No such file or directoryhalf/of/the/path/to/the/file.csv` Basically the error message, no space, then half of the path from the echo in line 2. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there whitespace in $file_name?

Comment: No, there are two dashes though

Comment: Can you just post the actual value of $file_name, perhaps with secret words changed to protect your privacy?

Comment: Basically `/path/to/my_file/on-the_server/name/of-file_201901020.csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't understand why you used "ssh -t" and "bash -l". They are not needed. They cause issues in my test environment.

That said, this kind of issues are very likely caused by invisible characters. To check if it is the case, you may want to `echo "[$file_name]"` so that you can see what is in it.

In this particular case, below please see what I've found:

```
   $ file_name=$(ssh -t testbox "ls -t /home/ec2-user/hello* | head -1")
   Connection to xxx closed. 

   $ echo "[$file_name]"
   ]/home/ec2-user/hello  # <--- the expected output is [/home/ec2-user/hello]

   $ scp testbox:$file_name ./
   : No such file or directory
```

In comparison, `ssh` without `-t` gives us the expected outcome:

```
$ file_name=$(ssh testbox  "ls -t /home/ec2-user/hello* | head -1")

$ echo "[$file_name]"
[/home/ec2-user/hello]

$ scp testbox:$file_name ./
hello                                    100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```